# How can i fix this: AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'lower' in py3?

Tags: python-3.x

```
current_users = ['mohammad', 'shervin' , 'ali', 'oskol' , 'pro_gamer']
new_users = ['ali', 'ahmad', 'shervin', 'lara', 'helena']
current_users.lower()
new_users.lower()
for new_user in new_users:
if new_user in current_users:
        print(new_user + " You must change your user name.")
else:
print("user name is available")
```

I need to know how to do case insensitive for this lists?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to apply the method to the individual strings in the list, not the list itself.

```
current_users = [user.lower() for user in current_users]
```

**UPDATE**

An alternate approach is to use sets which can figure out containment faster than your own loop:

```
current_users = ['mohammad', 'shervin' , 'ali', 'oskol' , 'pro_gamer']
new_users = ['ali', 'ahmad', 'shervin', 'lara', 'helena']

# normalize and convert to sets
current_users = set(user.lower() for user in current_users)
new_users = set(user.lower() for user in new_users)

# use sets to make decisions
conflicts = current_users & new_users
print("users {} already exist".format(', '.join(conflicts)))
uniques = new_users - current_users
print("users {} are available".format(', '.join(uniques)))
```

Comment: Thanks lot can you tell me how to new_users in current_users:              if 'Shervin' used 'shervin' must doesn't accept.

Comment: Since you lower cased "Shervin" to "shervin", you'll catch it.

Comment: It is all i need thank you so much man. i am sorry i can't vote cause my reputation is under 15.

Answer (score 0):

> `.lower()` can only be applied to strings.

Try this:

```
current_users = ['mohammad', 'shervin', 'ali', 'oskol', 'pro_gamer']
new_users = ['ali', 'ahmad', 'shervin', 'lara', 'helena']

current_users = [user.lower() for user in current_users]

for new_user in new_users:
  if new_user in current_users:
  print(new_user + " You must change your user name.")
else :
  print("user name is available")
```

Comment: This one really help me but can you tell me how to check new_users in current_users like this: if 'shervin' used 'Shervin' must doesn't accept.

Comment: Um, did you just cut and paste my fix for this?!

Comment: Consider rewording that a little. `.lower()` can be applied to any class that has a `lower` method. `list` doesn't, but others do.